# Unable to make a Get request with Redux Query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to use a `Get` request to pull API data and I am using `Redux Query`. Here is my code:

```
 export const userCartApi = api.injectEndpoints({
 endpoints: (builder)=>({
    getCart: builder.query({
        query: ()=>{
            return{
                url: "/cart",
                method: "get",
                
            };
        },
    }),


}),
overrideExisting: false
});
```

Inside the component where I used it:

```
 export const {useGetCartQuery } = userCartApi

import { useGetCartQuery } from "../../store/Features/CartApi/CartApi";
const [getCart, {data: cartData, isError: isCartError, isSuccess: isCartSuccess, error: 
 getCartEror, isLoading: isCartLoading,}] = useGetCartQuery();



const getCart = async()=>{
    await getCart()
 }
```

The store

```
export const Store = configureStore({
reducer:{
    [userApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer,
    [userCartApi.reducerPath]: userCartApi.reducer,
    session: sessionSlice,
    appLoader: appLoaderSlice,
    cart: cartReducer,
    user: userSlice,
},
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware)=> getDefaultMiddleware().concat(userApi.middleware)
});
```

The error that I am getting:

```
 Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
 In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

If I simply change the `getCart: builder.query` to `getCart: builder.mutation` and rename the hook to `useGetCartMutation` instead of `useGetCartQuery`, it works and fetches my data. Is there where I am missing a thing or two?

Answer (score 0):

It was all my mistake, please. I have seen how it is properly done and it is working now:
I simply needed to get the data this way:

```
const  {data: cartData, isError: isCartError, isSuccess: isCartSuccess, 
error: 
getCartEror, isLoading: isCartLoading,} = useGetCartQuery();
```

Instead of this way:

```
const [getCart, {data: cartData, isError: isCartError, isSuccess: isCartSuccess, 
error: 
getCartEror, isLoading: isCartLoading,}] = useGetCartQuery();
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you only need to set up your base api with the Redux store, not every injected api.